# what are the applications of fourier transform in modulation

Tags: modulation

what are the applications of Fourier transform in modulation ? What are modulation schemes that use Fourier transform? I guess, FSK & PSK are related to Fourier transform since it both have frequency and phase in their names respectively.

Comment: PSK and FSK have nothing to do with Fourier Transform.

Answer (score 3):

OFDM is usually modulated by using an IFFT (or FFT), using the DFT basis vectors for the multi-carrier orthogonality.